# Grouping operation for counting

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I've a pandas data frame, `df` with structure similar to

```
Timestamp, colA, colB, colC, colD
```

Now, I want a multi-indexed data frame

```
colA, colB, colC, colD, Time window, count
```

where `colA, colB, colC, colD` forms a multi-index index and time-window denotes a 5 minute time stamp window and count denotes the number of times the event identified by multi-index occurs in this rolling five minute window occurred. This operation is required to be performed every 30 minutes, t-35 mins to t-5, so there are 30 possible 5 min windows.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I've tried getting unique timestamps by doing a groupby size and and than sliding the window to get a count. This very moment I'm exploring the rolling function, which I think will serve the purpose.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your input data and the expected output ? See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)